Roxie query timeout
Exception
Reported by: WsEcl
Message: [ -6: timeout expired Target: C!:49918 -> 192.168.0.200:9876 (20), Raised in: jsocket.cpp, line 2034]
So i am encoding an image into a string using base64 , this string is very long.
this string is passed to roxie query.But the json response on the frontend , basically my prediction result of Image Model is getting timed out.This is running on localhost.
Before directly passing string to roxie query was giving me result , but after running my frontend , this seems to have also stopped working and resulting in same timout issue.

So is there a way to modify the timout parameter to prevent this from happening, also we are looking into using alternate frontends which have lower decoding time.

Is this AKS (local Docker) or bare-metal (in a VM)?
Typically, localhost defaults to port 8002. How are you submitting?  Do you send to port 8002 and then ESP sends to 9876?
Either way, there is this:
    <EspService build="_"
            buildSet="ws_ecl"
            description="WS ECL Service"
            name="ws_ecl"
            roxieTimeout="600"
            workunitTimeout="600">

roxieTimeout defaults to 600 sec if not specified. Is this query taking longer than 600 sec (5 minutes)? Perhaps adding this roxieTimeout parameter (if missing) and using a larger value, then restarting ESP might help.
Most Roxie queries are designed to produce a sub-second response, so 5 minutes is an egregiously long response time. You might want to consider moving this to Thor and pre-calculating your results for every image. But if Roxie is your only option, you might also look at using ALLNODES() in your processing code so it executes on all the Roxie nodes in parallel (like Thor does) instead of a single server.

Exception
Reported by: WsEcl
Message: [ -6: timeout expired Target: C!:44224 -> 192.168.0.200:9876 (26), Raised in: jsocket.cpp, line 2034] , can u please tell me how to fix this in Roxie ?This is just roxie query , no frontend. This happens everytime i use my frontend(streamlit)  and im forced to restart all the servers.
